# Как абстрагироваться от внешнего API?

Tags: c#, .net

Интересует мнение сообщества по работе c большими API.
А именно по абстракции от них т.к. методы используются в нескольких частях программы и хотелось бы менять их все сразу.

На данный момент я пользуюсь методом: [A Fluent Builder in C#](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/)

Как-то так, только с моими параметрами и тд.

```
Builder tb = new Builder();

Req team3 = tb.Create(app_id)
    .Using(Protocoll.Https)
    .UsingMethod(Http.Get)
    .WithPath(ApiEndpoint.PathToEndpoint)
    .WithFields("a", "b", "c")
    .FromPage(1)
    .Limit(100);
```

Потом это передается в класс с `HttpClient`, где он смотрит на параметры и создает запрос.

Ендпойнтов у меня штук 15 и у каждого свои параметры. Создавая общий билдер убирается валидация на клиенте. Т.е. я могу вызвать `WithFields` к эндпоинту, где его нет (который ничего не сделает), но в сеансе все равно покажется.

Если создавать индивидуально, то получается слишком уж много кода.

Кто как решает такую проблему?

Comment: Методы в разных API с разными именами и наборами параметров, которые семантически призваны делать одно и то же?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**:

- Хоть что-то лучше чем ничего
- Представленные диаграммы - не *UML* и не поддаются какому-нибудь принятому стандарту
- Я не спец и вопрос не до конца понял, ответ, возможно, не в кассу
- Простите если искорежил существующие паттерны или что-то не соответствующе назвал
- То, что представлено - только мысли, мнение, предположительные направления, которые надо еще прорабатывать и проверять. Не претендую на правильность. Что-то может быть вообще не подходит.

---

**1.** С моей точки зрения, не *fluent*, а даже простой сервис с набором методов здесь будет лучше. Update: Вашего случая не знаю, смотрите сами если что.

---

**2.** Посоветовал бы не передавать при каждом вызове параметры типа `Protocoll.Https`. А сделать представитель *API* на клиенте, который бы принимал подобные служебные параметры в конструктор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MyApiClient
{
    public MyApiClient(ContextInfo cxtInfo)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

`ContextInfo` - это и есть параметры типа `Protocoll.Https`, просто образно так назвал. Методы `MyApiClient` принимают параметры домена. Например, `TeamId`, `TeamSize`. А служебные типа `Protocoll.Https` - это внутренняя кухня. Они сами добавляются в запрос уже между `MyApiClient` и `MyApi`.

---

**3.** Еще одна почва для размышлений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под каждый *метод* сервиса создается свой *Query* или *Command*. Если производится запись или изменение данных, то *Command*. Если чтение данных, то *Query*.

*Update:* *Query* или *Command* - объект, который содержит параметры запроса.

```
//напимер,
public GetPersonQuery: IQuery<Person>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Мне кажется, что это только первый шажок к *SQRS*. Концепция *CQRS* в своем полном виде наследуется от *DDD* и достаточно сложная.

Получается, что если в *API* 10 методов, то количество *Query* + *Command* будет 10. Один *Endpoint* использует один набор квери и команд. Другой - другой. Так сказать, клиентская примочка является *QueryProcessor* и *CommandProcessor*.

```
public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}

public interface IQueryProcessor
{
    TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query);
}

// с командой примерно то же самое только она не возвращает результат
```

*Update:* Здесь может быть применим подход *IoC*

---

**4.** Еще одна почва для размышлений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Update:* Здесь так же может быть применим подход *IoC*

---

**5.** Подобно п.4, еще один вариант пищи для размышлений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]