# Архитектура проекта, взаимодействие между компонентами

Tags: java, spring, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, сервисы

Добрый день. Попробую описать задачу: был большой проект на JAVA, со временем проект еще больше рос и вносить правки в монолитное приложение было все тяжелее. Тогда было принято решение часть функционала выносить в «сервисы» с которыми ядро будет общаться по REST, но при этом сервисы выполняя вынесенную логику напрямую обращались в базу ядра для записи и чтения данных. То есть это не сервисы, а просто вынесенная часть бизнес логики за пределы монолитного ядра.  Со временем появилась идея все же сделать так называемые сервисы более независимыми и начать с того, перекрыть им возможность прямого доступа к данным.

Доступ к данным был разделен на 2 категории:

1. модификация(было решено делать через события и шины сообщений(брокер))
2. Чтения данных. И вот тут возник вопрос, как лучше его сделать. Пока на ум приходят 3 варианта:

   2.1. оставить возможность сервисам читать данные напрямую из БД

   2.2. делать методы внутренного api на стороне ядра(не хотелось бы, так как лищний раз трогать ядро не стоит)

   2.3. оборачивать sql запрос построенный в сервисе в какой-то объект, пересылать его ядру http запросом, уже в ядре проверить, что это именно select, выполнить и вернут ответ обратно сервису в ввиде массива json. А сервис уже его пропарсит в нормальный список объектов с которым и будет работать.

К сожалению проект очень большой и переписать его нет возможности, стоит задачу как можно меньшей кровью улучшить его архитектуру и взаимодействие ядра с сервисами  «сервисами».

Хотелось бы узнать мнение знатоков по вопросам:

1. нормальная ли это схема в данном случаи( разделение чтения и записи)?
2. какой из вариантов для чтения предпочесть?
3. если все же использовать вариант с пересылкой упакованного sql запроса  и выполнения его ядром, какой фрэймворк посоветуете? Я вот обратил внимание на JOOQ не знаю подойдет ли он для этого или нет?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

1. Мне кажется, что отделить чтение от записи - очень хорошая идея. У чтения и записи разные специфики. Для чтения нужно извлечь много всего, еще и подтянуть много дополнительного. При записи модифицируется меньший объем данных, возможно, одна или две строчки из одной или двух таблиц. При записи добавляется логика. При работе в команде такое разделение очень удобно: 2 не пересекающиеся задачи, по крайней мере с точки зрения *Application Services Layer*. Одна комплексная задача разбивается на две попроще. Возможно даже использовать разные механизмы работы с бд. В нашем *C#-ком* проекте для чтения - *NHibernate* (аналог джавовского *Hibernate*), а для записи - *Dapper*, грубо говоря, *SQL*- скрипты.
2. Мне кажется, что:

   - 2.1. (оставить возможность сервисам читать данные из бд) - не перспективен. Хорошо иметь слой сервисов, которые возвращают *JSON*, тогда по принципам *SOLID* можно будет эти сервисы переиспользовать для клиентов сделанных на разных технологиях.
   - 2.3. (пересылать *SQL*-запрос) тоже как-то не красиво, потому что БД в какой-то степени остается не изолированной, что усложнит будущее развитие системы при добавлении требований по безопасности или авторизации. У меня опыта недостаточно, но этот вариант видится не красивым. Возможно есть еще и другие причины, почему.
   - **2.2.** (делать методы внутреннего апи) - самый подходящий с моей т.з., потому что можно легко расширять фукционал. Хотя я не уверен (реального случая не знаю). Чтобы не менять сервисы каждый раз, можно иметь не апи в виде сервисов со многими методами, а много *Query*. Каждая *Query* - набор параметров для выполнения одной операции чтения. У каждой *Query* есть *QueryHandler*, который ее выполняет. Можно *Query* вынести в отдельную сборку, чтоб и клиент и сервер пользовались, и делать изменения только в этой сборке. Знаю, [как реализовать этот подход с *Query* на *C#* (примерно, частично - 3 пункт ответа по ссылке)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502596/185885), но на *Java*, с учетом специфики *WebApi* - не знаю.
3. Не знаю.

В конечном итоге, можно прийти к *CQRS*.